# Write React components in one project and sync them in another project on same computer

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a huge React project with a huge team, and the compiling time is 10+ seconds, so I made my own react app and build components there, and copy them over when finished. This works but manually copying the components are very tedious and prone to error.

I tried using symlinks, turned out it doesn't compile, after some research I found that react doesn't allow importing from outside of the src folder.

I tried doing it on a separate branch and bypass the majority of the codebase and just do my own things, but that involves changing other people's 
code but never push them while pushing my own code, which is also prone to error.

This is a tightly administrated computer, I can't use Dropbox or Google Drive, and I can't publish to npm, and my components are not publish-ready anyways.

What's the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no one best way to do this, however this is a common problem and there are several solutions:

**Note: You don't need to connect to the public npm registry to have an npm-like experience.**

1) Create a "monorepo" via [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/)

Separate the development of your React components with other "modules" within the same repository. You get all the benefit of versioning like with npm packages, but it's all within the same project folder. Let's say you're creating a new component on some branch `feature/fancyComponent`.. a different developer can check out that branch and import your component as if it were a package installed in your `node_modules` folder... `import FancyComponent from 'react-components/FancyComponent'`

2) Use an npm registry proxy [verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio)

Instead of a monorepo, use as many repos as you need and publish your components to your local npm registry. You can set things up so that when you `npm install somecomponent` it will look at your local registry first, then fallback to npm.